# How to change WS-Trust security in Dynamics Crm project

Tags: authentication, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

My situation is suddenly I get :Value cannot be null.Parameter name: service  when trying to get organizationservice,after googling I found that my proj uses WS-Trust security and it might create my problems,

after reading about it in ms docs I found that this might be my case :

If you are accessing the CrmServiceClient.OrganizationServiceProxy property:

Remove all use of that property in your code. CrmServiceClient implements IOrganizationService and exposes everything that is settable for the organization service proxy.

My question is if I remove my use of :

```
 CrmServiceClient crmServiceClient = new CrmServiceClient( connectionString);
IOrganizationService organizationService = (IOrganizationService)crmServiceClient.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null
? (IOrganizationService)crmServiceClient.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)crmServiceClient.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

what could be the replacement ?

Does anyone deal with that case? Is there an other way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is probably due to an authentication problem, such as expired password. That will cause the Service property to be null. You can look at the LastCrmError property before using the returned client in order to detect this situation. I have used code like this:

```
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient c = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(connStr);

// At least when using Office365 authentication, invalid (or expired password) will show up in LastCrmError.
// I have not seen LastCrmException, but it sounds bad, too, to check that too.
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.LastCrmError) && c.LastCrmException == null))
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "CRM Error: " + c.LastCrmError);
    if (c.LastCrmException != null)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("CRM Exception: " + c.LastCrmException.Message);
        Console.Error.WriteLine("CRM Exception details: " + c.LastCrmException.ToString());
    }
    Environment.Exit(99);
}
```

This code will *probably* stop working as WS-Trust security is removed and you upgrade to the newer 9.2.x SDK, as described in [Use of Office365 authentication with the WS-Trust security protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/authenticate-office365-deprecation)

I was thinking of future-proofing the code by only using methods from the IOrganizationService interface (see below), but CrmLastError is not available in the IOrganizationProxy interface, so for now I'm using the code above. But the rest of the code base only relies on the IOrganizationService interface, so the code re-work should be minimal.

```
IOrganizationService c = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(connStr);
```